# Where can I find more Ubuntu 13.10 unity scopes

Tags: 13.10, scopes

I want to find more unity scopes for ubuntu 13.10 because I am new to Ubuntu and I want to use lots of unity scopes, if you can help me find some that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Open up software-center, search `unity-scope`.